# <Shift+Shift> layout switching works not as expected

Tags: unity, keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

I have two keyboard layouts, English and Russian. I selected `<Shift+Shift>` as a layout change shortcut and have used it for years. Earlier, on Elementary Luna, Gnome 3, the layout switched as soon as I pressed one <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while holding another. This made the following use-case possible:

- Type some Russian text
- Press and hold R-Shift
- Press and release L-Shift to change layout
- Type some English text (uppercase) or special symbols such as $ or backtick
- Press and release L-Shift once again to change layout back to Russian
- Release R-Shift and continue working with Russian layout.

However, when I migrated to Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity, this shortcut behavior changed. Now it switches the layout only when BOTH <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys have been pressed and released, making the described use-case not possible.

Can it be tuned somehow? I tried several options in Settings but couldn't find anything related.

Answer (score 3):

In Unity you can achieve a similar behaviour with the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

This shortcut will let you to switch to next *input source*. Changing *input source* will change your keyboard layout.
An example of using this is:

1. Current input source is set to `Russian`;
2. You can type something in `Russian`;
3. When you need `English` keyboard layout press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to switch to next *input source*;
4. Type some `English` text (e.g. <kbd>$</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd>);
5. Come back to `Russian` keyboard layout pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Now you can follow this step to set this behaviour as described above:

1. Open `System Settings` and select `Keyboard`.
2. In the `Typing` tab look at the window bottom left and select `Text Entry`.
3. You should see a new window that show on the left a list of *input sources* that you can use (*and switch between*) and on the right some options like shortcut to switch between input sources.
4. If you have already `Russian` and `English` as *input sources* you don't have to do anything, unless you want to change the shortcut. Instead if you have only `Russian` as *input source* you can add `English` *input source* pressing the `+` button under the list and select an `English` *input source (e.g. `English (US)`).
5. If you want to track which *input source* is active you can tick the checkbox in the bottom left beside to `Show current input source in the menu bar`.
6. Now you should be able to obtain the behaviour described above that will let you to switch between *input source* in an easy way.

I hope this could help you.

---

P.S. I did the same thing with my *input sources*: `Italian` and `English`.

[image: text entry]